# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. Runs in Access not in VB

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, vb.net, ms-access-2007

This query runs perfectly in Access 2007 but when I try to execute it in my code I get Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. Someone please help.

```
Dim sql1 As String
sql1 = "INSERT INTO CustomerDtl (KioskID, ClientID, Language, SalesType) VALUES ('AD903',1,'English','Wholesale')"
ObjAccess.ExecuteQuery(sql1)
```

And this is the ExecuteReader function:

```
Public Function ExecuteQuery(ByVal SQLQuery As String)

        'This Function Executes SQL Statement against connection and returns number of rows affected'

        dbCommand = New OleDbCommand
        Call OpenConnection()

        With dbCommand
            .Connection = dbConnection
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = SQLQuery
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
            .Dispose()
        End With

        Call CloseConnection()

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Langauge` is a reserved keyword. escape it by wrapping `[ ]`.

```
sql1 = "INSERT INTO CustomerDtl (..., [Language], ....) VALUES(...)"
```

- [MS Access Reserved Keywords](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx)

Comment: consider also using parameters to avoid injection. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/26/Parameter-Queries-in-ASP.NET-with-MS-Access